# Is this proof that $\lim_{n \to \infty} c^{1/n} = 1$ if $c > 0$ correct?

Tags: calculus, limits

I would like to ask whether the below proof that $\lim_{n \to \infty} c^{1/n} = 1$ if $c > 0$ is correct.

**Proof attempt**:

We want to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} c^{1/n} = 1$. That is, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an $N > 0$ such that, if $n > N$, then $|c^{1/n} - 1| < \varepsilon$. This last inequality is equivalent to $1 - \varepsilon < c^{1/n} < 1 + \varepsilon$.

Note that, since $c$ is positive, $c^{1/n} < 1 + \varepsilon$ is equivalent to $c < (1 + \varepsilon)^n$. Since $1 + \varepsilon > 1$, the expression $(1 + \varepsilon)^n$ increases without bound as $n \to \infty$. So, we must have $c < (1 + \varepsilon)^n$ for sufficiently large $n$, and thus $c^{1/n} < 1 + \varepsilon$.

Now, we have to show that $c^{1/n} > 1 - \varepsilon$. By cases:

1. If $0 < \varepsilon < 1$, then $0 < 1 - \varepsilon < 1$, and so $(1 - \varepsilon)^n$ decreases towards $0$ as $n$ increases. So, we must have $c > (1 - \varepsilon)^n$ for sufficiently large $n$. So, $c^{1/n} > 1 - \varepsilon$.
2. If $\varepsilon \geq 1$, then it is clear that $c^{1/n} > 1 - \varepsilon$, since $1 - \varepsilon \leq 0$.

This shows that $|c^{1/n} - 1| < \varepsilon$, and thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} c^{1/n} = 1$.

Comment: "Since $1+\epsilon>1,$ $(1+\epsilon)^n$ increases without bound." That probably requires proof.

Comment: And likewise, why $(1-\epsilon)^n$ decreases to $0.$

Comment: First thought is to use Bernoulli's inequality. But maybe there is an even more elementary argument without Bernoulli...

Comment: Yes. See here for the standard result: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality#Generalization_of_exponent

Comment: You could also use an argument like: if $c>1$, then $c^{1/n}$ is a decreasing sequence bounded below by 1, so it has a limit $L\ge 1$.  But then, the $2n$ terms form a subsequence which also converge to $L$, which implies $L^2 = L$.  The conclusion is that $L=1$.  The case $0<c<1$ would be similar (except you need a tiny bit more work in that case to rule out the solution $L=0$).

Comment: Thank you for the comments. The main reason why I was suspicious of the correctness of the presented proof is because most proofs I find out there are divided in two cases ($0 < c < 1$, $c = 1$ and $c > 1 $), but the proof I gave doesn't need to do that. So, I was wondering whether there was something I had missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (alternatively) apply the continuity of the exponential function to conclude that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}c^{1/n} & = \lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\ln(c^{1/n})\right)\\\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\frac{\ln(c)}{n}\right)\\\\
& = \exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(c)}{n}\right)\\\\
& = \exp(0) = 1
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!